# Failed to convert value of type HashMap to String

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a way to block and unblock users in Kotlin. So far I have retrieved the other user's id and put it in the Firebase Database. after it is in the database, the app crashes. Here is the code to get the uid and put it in the database:

```
val mapUid = p0.child("uid").value
val hashMap: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
hashMap["uid"] = mapUid.toString()

val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
ref.child(firebaseUser.uid).child("blockedUsers")
.child(mapUid.toString()).setValue(hashMap)
```

Here is the database:

[image: FirebaseDatabase Screenshot]

Here is the Logcat:

```
2020-10-01 19:49:01.625 9291-9291/com.score.scorev2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.score.scorev2, PID: 9291
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertString(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:425)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:216)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:178)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:592)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:562)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:432)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:231)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:203)
        at com.score.scorev2.Fragments.SearchFragment$searchForUsers$1.onDataChange(SearchFragment.kt:94)
```

The logcat says the error is in SearchFragment. Though it was working before. When I 'fix' that error, the next activity crashes. So here is SearchFragment Ln 94:

```
private fun searchForUsers(str: String){
    var firebaseUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    val queryUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        .child("Users").orderByChild("search")
        .startAt(str)
        .endAt(str + "\uf8ff")

queryUsers.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        (mUsers as ArrayList<Users>).clear()

            for (snapshot in p0.children){
94:                val user: Users? = snapshot.getValue(Users::class.java)
                if (!(user!!.getUID()).equals(firebaseUserID)){
                    (mUsers as ArrayList<Users>).add(user)
                }
            }
            userAdapter = UserAdapter(p0, context!!, mUsers!!, false)
            recyclerView!!.adapter = userAdapter
        }
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })
}
```

Here is my Users class

```
class Users {

    fun users() {}

    private var uid: String = ""
    private var blockedUsers: String = ""
    private var isBlocked: Boolean = false

    fun users(
        uid: String,
        blockedUsers: String,
        isBlocked: Boolean,
    ) {
        this.uid = uid
        this.blockedUsers = blockedUsers
        this.isBlocked = isBlocked
    }

    fun toMap(): Map<String, Any?> {
        return mapOf(
            "uid" to uid,
            "blockedUsers" to blockedUsers,
            "isBlocked" to isBlocked,
        )
    }
    constructor()
    constructor(
        uid: String,
        blockedUsers: String,
        isBlocked: Boolean,
    ) {
        this.uid = uid
        this.blockedUsers = blockedUsers
        this.isBlocked = isBlocked
    }

    fun getUID(): String?{ return uid }
    fun setUID(uid: String){ this.uid = uid }

    fun getBlockedUsers(): String?{ return blockedUsers }
    fun setBlockedUsers(blockedUsers: String){ this.blockedUsers = blockedUsers }

    fun getIsBlocked(): Boolean?{ return isBlocked }
    fun setIsBlocked(isBlocked: Boolean){ this.isBlocked = isBlocked }
}
```

Also, when I do not have the child "mapUid.toString()" it seems to work, but then I don't think I can properly sort through the different uids.

Comment: What does your `Users` class look like?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added my Users class above, thanks.

Comment: This seems wrong in your `Users` class: `fun getBlockedUsers(): String?{ return blockedUsers }`. It says that a child node is `/users` has a `blockedUsers` property that is a string value. Looking at your JSON that is not the case: `blockedUsers` is a complex object that you'll need to complete model in able to read it from the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ah alright, thank you! If you don't mind, could you point me towards some links or something to help me do that? Please and thank you!

Comment: It looks like a dictionary, where each value is an object that has a `uid` property.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry, I'm very new to this, what do you mean? Do you happen to know an article that could explain this further?

Comment: Your `Users` models a single child node under `/users` in your database. You'll need to create a similar class to represent each child node of `blockedUsers`. This class will have a single `uid` property. Then with that class the `blockedUsers` property in `Users` is a `Map<String, BlockedUser>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems wrong in your `Users` class:

```
fun getBlockedUsers(): String?{ return blockedUsers }
```

It says that each child node of `/users` has a `blockedUsers` property that is a string value. Looking at your JSON that is not the case: `blockedUsers` is a complex object that you'll need recreate that model in your Java class in order to be able to read it.

Your `Users` class models a single child node under `/users` in your database. You'll need to create a similar class to represent each child node of `blockedUsers`. This class will have a single `uid` property. Then with that class the `blockedUsers` property in `Users` is a `Map<String, BlockedUser>`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your problem has nothing to do with "How to block and unblock users in Kotlin/Firebase?", so you should change that title, your problem is "Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String" and in your case, it's because `p0.child("uid").value` returns a HashMap, not a String.

The funny thing is that I went looking for the `child()` function documentation and noticed that in `Reference` class there's no `value` parameter.

Anyway, you can look here and try figure out what is happening:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#child

Comment: The `p0` is most likely a `DataSnapshot` object, which has a `getValue()` method defined [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/ktx/package-summary#(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot).getValue()), which is exposed in Kotlin as a `.value` property.